# Having trouble with a for loop evaluating incorrectly

Tags: java, loops, evaluation

I was having this problem today and I'm not sure what causes it. The following code:

```
int totWidth = 19;
String header = "Kalle's Numbers";
if (totWidth > header.length()) {
    for (int j = 0; j < totWidth / 2 - header.length() / 2; j++) {
        header += " ";
    }
}
System.out.println(header + "|");
```

should yield

```
Kalle's Numbers  |
```

but instead yields

```
Kalle's Numbers |
```

I modified the code a little bit by adding a variable "rightSpaces"

```
int totWidth = 19;
String header = "Kalle's Numbers";
if (totWidth > header.length()) {
    int rightSpaces = totWidth / 2 - header.length() / 2;
    for (int j = 0; j < rightSpaces; j++) {
        header += " ";
    }
}
System.out.println(header + "|");
```

and suddenly it yields the correct output. Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because as it iterates through your `for` loop, you change the length of `header` by adding a space. So `header.length() / 2` in your loop's continuation condition is potentially a different value each time.

What you've done in your second example fixes this problem by evaluating it once.